# Best Practice When Using Large Dictionary 1 Million+ Key/Value pairs

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a `dict = [String:[String]]` dictionary that contains 1 Million+ key value pairs, what is the most efficient way to store and retrieve such large amount of data? Should I transform dictionary into `JSON`, `XML` or `plist` file ?

Editing the original question to make it more clear.

- The data will not be modified/written to, it will only be read.
- The format of data is `["Key" : ["Value0", "Value1", "Value2"...]]`
- The data is sorted [a-z]

Comment: The `JSON` is the best option there.

Comment: When you say "Store" the data, I assume you are trying to store the values locally on the device. If yes, then you should go with CoreData or any other DB solution SQLite.